# With Algolia, how to pass the query string created by urlSync into the php client?

Tags: javascript, php, search, algolia

Working with the Algolia InstantSearch js library and the PHP client, I wish to pass the query string created by InstantSearch urlSync into the PHP library's search method. Is there a convenient way to do this or will I have to translate the query string to the params the library expects by myself?

For example, I have the string:

`?q=&hPP=1000&idx=myindex&p=0&dFR%5Bcolor%5D%5B0%5D=orange&is_v=1`

Ideally I would like to

```
$client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client("x", "x");
$index = $client->initIndex($_GET['idx']);
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $params);
$res = $index->search('', $params);
```

but doing so throws an error that there are unexpected properties in the params passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's indeed not possible to reuse the instant search URL in your back-end using Algolia clients. I would assume you're asking this for SEO purposes, which is a definitely valid point.

The only language in which this would be doable at the moment is JavaScript.
Indeed, this logic is extractable from the underlying library of  `instantsearch.js`: [`algoliasearch-helper-js`](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js/).

- Use [`getStateFromQueryString`](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html#url) to get the state
- Create a [new helper instance](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html#instantiate)
- Set its state with the previously retrieved one using [`setState`](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html#AlgoliaSearchHelper#setState)
- Finally, use the undocumented (and soon deprecated) [`getQuery` method](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js/blob/develop/src/algoliasearch.helper.js#L122)

You could actually add this logic in the front-end, URL-encode this query and set it in a custom parameter that you'd decode in your back-end. That's pretty ugly but it could work (it might not fit in the maximum URI length though).

In the front-end, you wouldn't have to go through the process of extracting the state from the URL and setting the state to a new helper, you can simply use `search.helper` - where `search` is your `instantsearch.js` instance.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Yes, the goal is SEO; I want a cached result to be served before js is ready. It would be great if the names used by syncUrl would be compatible with the filter params, and these were consistent throughout all clients (maybe they already are, I haven't used any but js and PHP so far). But that's just a suggestion. For now I'll just map the passed URL params to PHP, we have solid control over what we will receive and getting js to run on the server just for this is overkill. Thanks again!

Comment: This is definitely a good suggestion and is being discussed internally. Since any change on this would likely not be before a few months, this solution would likely be the best one available in the meantime. But obviously, we're trying our best to unify the experience across all our supported platforms. :)